# Inconsistent interpretations for the second parameter of the Gamma distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-process, gamma-distribution

The following question is motivated by material from pages 358-364 of Blitzstein and Hwang's [***Introduction to Probability***](https://books.google.com/books?id=z2POBQAAQBAJ).  (NB: I have modified the book's notation in various places to make my question clearer.)

---

First, suppose that $\{N_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is a family of r.v.s indexed by the set $\mathbb{R}^+$ of positive reals, and that for each $t \in \mathbb{R}^+$, we have $N_t \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda t)$, where $\lambda$ is an *unknown* parameter, independent of $t$.

Or, to put it in Bayesian terms, we have

$$
    N_t\mid\lambda \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda t)
$$

Now, take<sup>1</sup> $\mathrm{Gamma}(n_0, t_0)$ as the (conjugate) prior distribution for $\lambda$.  I.e.

$$
    \lambda \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(n_0, t_0)
$$

Starting from these assumptions, the authors derive (p. 362-364) the posterior distribution for $\lambda$ as

$$
    \lambda \mid (N_t = n) \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(n_0 + n, t_0 + t)
$$

Furthermore, authors derive (p. 364) the posterior expectation for $\lambda$ as

$$
    \operatorname{E}(\lambda \mid N_t = n) = \frac{n_0 + n}{t_0 + t}
$$

These results suggest that the first parameter of a $\mathrm{Gamma}$ distribution is akin to a *count* (of occurrences), and the second one is akin to an *length of time*.

Under this interpretation, the *prior* distribution $\mathrm{Gamma}(n_0, t_0)$ would be obtained from the total number of occurrences ($n_0$) observed over one or more intervals of time adding up to a total of $t_0$ (time units).  To get the *posterior* distribution, we update the parameters of the prior's $\mathrm{Gamma}$ by adding a number of occurrences ($n$) observed during a new interval of time of length $t$, so that now we have a total of $n_0 + n$ occurrences observed in a cumulative interval of length $t_0 + t$.

---

On the other hand, on p. 358 the authors note that a $\mathrm{Gamma}(1, \nu)$ distribution is equivalent to an $\mathrm{Exponential}(\nu)$ distribution, defined as the distribution whose PDF is $f(t) = \nu e^{-\nu t}$.  In this case, the second parameter of the $\mathrm{Gamma}$ distribution seems to be behaving like a *rate* (occurrences per unit time), rather than a length of time.

---

I'm puzzled by these two radically different interpretations of the $\mathrm{Gamma}$ distribution's second parameter (first as a length of time, and later as a rate).

Is my reasoning above wrong?  If not, is there some way to unify or rationalize such divergent interpretations?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The book uses the convention that $\mathrm{Gamma}(a, b)$ is the distrubtion whose PDF is $f(x) = \frac{(b x)^a e^{-b x}}{x \Gamma(a)},\; x > 0$.</sup>

Comment: If `we have a total of ` $n_0+n$ `occurrences observed in a cumulative interval of length `$t_0+t$, then $\frac{n_0 + n}{t_0 + t}$ looks like a "rate" to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Just_to_Answer: Yes, but that expression refers to the posterior expectation of $\lambda$, a *Poisson* parameter.  In this post I'm discussing the interpretation of the second parameter for the Gamma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are, more or less, looking at different *coordinate* systems.

The conjugate prior distribution is for a *rate* parameter, while the other is the distribution for a *time* random variable.

$$\bbox[2ex]{\underbrace{\quad \lambda}_{\text{a rate}} \sim \mathcal{Gamma}(n_0,\underbrace{t_0\qquad}_{\text{time interval}})} \\ \text{versus}\\\bbox[2ex]{\underbrace{\qquad\quad X}_{\text{a time interval}} \sim \mathcal{Gamma}(1 ,\underbrace{\nu\quad}_{\text{a rate}})}$$

That is all.

Answer (score 1):

Two conventional ways of parametrizing the family of Gamma distributions are these:
\begin{align}
& \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} \left( \frac t \mu \right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-t/\mu} \, \frac{dt} \mu \qquad \text{for } t\ge0 \\[12pt]
& \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} (\lambda t)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda t} \, (\lambda\, dt) \qquad \text{for } t\ge 0
\end{align}

If $\lambda = \dfrac 1 \mu$ then these are both the same distribution, with expected value $\alpha\mu = \dfrac\alpha \lambda.$ If $t$ is measured in units of time, then so is $\mu,$ and $\lambda$ is then in units of frequency (i.e. $\lambda$ is a *rate*).

Comment: That's not the issue here.  They're using the same distribution (shape-rate parameters); just for different coordinate systems.